# KendoDatePicker date format as "21 Aug 2018"

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I'm using KendoDatePicker in my application. I want the datepicker to show the date in the format "21 Aug 2018". How can this be possible with kendo ?

Answer (score 2):

@Agil, you need to add format with your kendoDatePicker declaration.

Blow is my sample working code. Try it and let me know whether it works for you or not?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#datetimepicker").kendoDatePicker({
   value: new Date(),
  dateInput: true,
  format: "dd MMMM yyyy"
 });
});
```

```css
html{ 
  font-size: 14px; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div class="demo-section k-content">
   <h4>Remind me on</h4>
   <input id="datetimepicker" title="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```